# How to find all the values for a given key in a Nested Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Hi I am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and Rails 5. I have a nested Hash as follows:-

```
{
  "lines":[
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"IGA",
          "Left":619,
          "Top":948,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":9
        },
        {
          "WordText":"AU",
          "Left":905,
          "Top":951,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":18
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":948
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"TAX",
          "Left":629,
          "Top":977,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":28
        },
        {
          "WordText":"485",
          "Left":895,
          "Top":980,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":28
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":977
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"IRRESISTIBLY",
          "Left":700,
          "Top":1103,
          "Height":16,
          "Width":105
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":16,
      "MinTop":1103
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"LOW",
          "Left":700,
          "Top":1124,
          "Height":15,
          "Width":39
        },
        {
          "WordText":"PRICES.",
          "Left":745,
          "Top":1124,
          "Height":15,
          "Width":61
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":15,
      "MinTop":1124
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"EVERYTHING.",
          "Left":701,
          "Top":1147,
          "Height":16,
          "Width":104
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":16,
      "MinTop":1147
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"EVERY",
          "Left":711,
          "Top":1169,
          "Height":16,
          "Width":48
        },
        {
          "WordText":"DAY.",
          "Left":764,
          "Top":1169,
          "Height":16,
          "Width":31
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":16,
      "MinTop":1169
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"06/02/18",
          "Left":581,
          "Top":1826,
          "Height":19,
          "Width":78
        },
        {
          "WordText":"16:25",
          "Left":671,
          "Top":1826,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":46
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":20,
      "MinTop":1826
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"0553",
          "Left":640,
          "Top":1854,
          "Height":19,
          "Width":38
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":19,
      "MinTop":1854
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"CREDIT",
          "Left":581,
          "Top":1882,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":57
        },
        {
          "WordText":"ACCOUNT",
          "Left":650,
          "Top":1882,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":67
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":1882
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"APSN",
          "Left":580,
          "Top":1910,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":38
        },
        {
          "WordText":"0000",
          "Left":630,
          "Top":1911,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":37
        },
        {
          "WordText":"ATC",
          "Left":688,
          "Top":1911,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":29
        },
        {
          "WordText":"0543",
          "Left":728,
          "Top":1912,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":38
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":1910
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"PURCHASE",
          "Left":580,
          "Top":1939,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":77
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":20,
      "MinTop":1939
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"(OO)APPRDVED",
          "Left":837,
          "Top":1970,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":116
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":1970
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"28",
          "Left":735,
          "Top":2224,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":19
        },
        {
          "WordText":"day",
          "Left":764,
          "Top":2224,
          "Height":24,
          "Width":29
        },
        {
          "WordText":"returns",
          "Left":804,
          "Top":2226,
          "Height":19,
          "Width":68
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":24,
      "MinTop":2224
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"WE",
          "Left":537,
          "Top":2251,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":19
        },
        {
          "WordText":"WITH",
          "Left":881,
          "Top":2254,
          "Height":19,
          "Width":39
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":20,
      "MinTop":2251
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"YOUR",
          "Left":538,
          "Top":2278,
          "Height":21,
          "Width":37
        },
        {
          "WordText":"VISIT",
          "Left":812,
          "Top":2280,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":49
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":21,
      "MinTop":2278
    },
    {
      "Words":[
        {
          "WordText":"kvt-",
          "Left":674,
          "Top":2308,
          "Height":20,
          "Width":57
        },
        {
          "WordText":"icy",
          "Left":913,
          "Top":2310,
          "Height":22,
          "Width":28
        }
      ],
      "MaxHeight":24,
      "MinTop":2308
    }
  ],
  "HasOverlay":true,
  "Message":"Total lines: 60"
}
```

I need to find all the values of a key 'WordText', as you can see key is common in the hash. Is there any method to find all the values of a key in the nested hash?. Please help me how can i get all the values of the key 'WordText'. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each WordText key is inside a Words key which is at the same time, inside one called lines, so you could map them. First accessing the `lines` key, then over each `Words` get the `WordText`:

```
p nested[:lines].flat_map { |hash| hash[:Words].map { |inner| inner[:WordText] } }

# ["IGA", "AU", "TAX", "485", "IRRESISTIBLY", ...]
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i Avoid using {...} for multi-line blocks?